# Get a List of User-Defined Controls From Current Namespace

Tags: c#, runtime, controls, user-defined

How could I get a list of all user-defined controls that were added to current namespace?
I am using C# 2010.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read about reflection?

Comment: Yes I tried. Controls are add to namespace and the namespace is not an object. I could not extract list of user-defined controls from namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these method i can extract list of all user-defined controls in my project and create an instance of the User-defined Control by it's name on my form.

```
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();           // Get my CurrentDomain Object
        Assembly myType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();                  // Extract list of all references in my project
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)                                // Search for the library that contains namespace that have needed controls
        {
            if (assembly.GetName().ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf("FIBACONTROLS") > -1)   
            {
                myType = assembly;                                          // Get All types in the library
                List<Type> myTps = myType.GetTypes().ToList();


                Type mT = null;
                foreach (Type selType in myTps)                             // Find the type that refer to needed user-defined control
                {
                    if (selType.Name.ToUpper() == "FIBACOLORPICKER")
                    {
                        mT = selType;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mT == null)
                    return;

                object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(mT);           // Created an instance on the type
                Control mFib = (Control)myInstance;                         // create the control's object
                mFib.Name = "Hahah";                                        // add the control to my form
                mFib.Left = 100;
                mFib.Top = 200;
                mFib.Visible = true;

                this.Controls.Add(mFib);

                break;
            }
        }
```

I try add some comment to code to describe it.

It work and sure there are some better way to do it, but I'm new one in C# and I am sure that the solution that I found is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection. Try this code:

```
public static class ControlsFinder
{
    public static List<Type> FindControls(Assembly controlsLibrary,
        string rootNamespace, bool includeNestedTypes = true)
    {
        var parent = typeof(UserControl);
        return controlsLibrary.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => (includeNestedTypes 
                ? t.FullName.StartsWith(rootNamespace)
                : t.FullName.Equals($"{rootNamespace}.{t.Name}"))
                && parent.IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var controls = ControlsFinder.FindControls(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "WinFrm");
```

If you only want names you can select them from `controls`:

```
var names = controls.Select(t => t.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't know where is wrong. I made a user-defined control and added it's project to my main app project's reference. Now in no way I can get the name of my user-defined control that were added to my main app project. This code return controls with 0 member too.

Comment: I've updated answer. Be sure to pass correct assembly into `FindControls`. I've used `GetExecutingAssembly`, but it is just an example

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not work. How could I upload my simplified project?

Comment: @Farzin you can use [gihub](https://github.com/)  or [bibucket](https://bitbucket.org/). Or any other source control systems

Comment: I find solution by myself. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Farzin I think you should post your solution here as answer